# chkconfig $svc reset does not take effect if executed by higher pri init.d service at boot?

Tags: centos, init.d, chkconfig

On a centos 6 derivative (Amazon Linux), I have an init.d script ecrinit that is meant to enable/disable some services at system startup (based on contents of a properties file on disk):

```
if [[ "$nodeType" == "foo" ]]; then
 #turn off mysql, turn on proftpd
 service mysqld stop
 chkconfig mysqld off # prevent lower-pri mysqld service from 

 chkconfig proftpd reset # re-enables at run levels 2-4
fi
```

Since start pri of ecrinit is 60 and of proftpd is 88, I expected the latter to be started by the boot process, since calling chkconfig reset above ensured that appropriate files exist in /etc/rc3.d (confirmed).

But that does not seem to be the case, as 'start' is never called on proftpd (I added a log statement to latter script's body to confirm) if I issue 'chkconfig proftpd off' before doing 'init 6'. **In other words, it seems that the boot process checks contents of /etc/rc3.d before ecrinit is executed (and does not detect new files in same dir during boot process)...**

Is that the expected behavior? If so, how can i control which services should be enabled on a given startup (and avoid manually starting them to preserve priority order)?

**startup script heads**

```
[root@lb1 ~]# head /etc/init.d/proftpd
#!/bin/bash
# $Id: proftpd.init,v 1.1 2004/02/26 17:54:30 thias Exp $
#
# proftpd       This shell script takes care of starting and stopping
#               proftpd.
#
# chkconfig: 234 88 12
# description: ProFTPd is an enhanced FTP server with a focus towards \
#              simplicity, security, and ease of configuration. \
#              It features a very Apache-like configuration syntax, \
[root@lb1 ~]# head /etc/init.d/ecrinit
#!/bin/bash
#
# chkconfig: 234 19 10
# description: Initializes stuff
```

**chkconfig --list (after boot)**

```
[root@lb1 rc3.d]$ chkconfig --list proftpd
proftpd         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:off   6:off
[root@lb1 rc3.d]$ chkconfig --list ecrinit
ecrinit         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:off   6:off
```

**uname -a**
Linux 2.6.35.14-97.44.amzn1.i686 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 16:03:22 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `/etc/rc` script, which does the following:

```
for i in /etc/rc$runlevel.d/S* ; do
```

the script has already expanded the list of available startup scripts before they run; changes made via `chkconfig` (or direct filesystem manipulation) aren't going to be visible.

If you move your logic to the end of the boot process, you can start the services explicitly:

```
if [[ "$nodeType" == "foo" ]]; then
 #turn off mysql, turn on proftpd
 service mysqld stop
 chkconfig mysqld off # prevent lower-pri mysqld service from 

 service protftpd start
fi
```

There's probably not much point in using `chkconfig` to enable `proftpd` in this example, since presumably the logic here will start it anyway next time the system boots.

You may also want to investigate [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), which is good at doing exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: thx - for pointing to /etc/rc & puppet